# delegate with parameters defined but used as a parameter without its own parameters? c#

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to understand the following code.

It has a function *create* with a delegate *CallbackRcvData* as a parameter.
The delegate is is defined with parameters, but the function in the code just states the delegate as a parameter, but that parameter/delegate does not have the required parameters from his own definition. And this construct works wonderfully. I don't get it...I'm new to delegates. If you need more Information, please let me know

The function OpenConnection comes from a dll.

```
public class myClass
{    
    public delegate int CallbackRcvData(UInt32 ConnectionId, IntPtr Data, Int32 size, Int32 Status);

    public void Create(string TargetName, string Login, string Password, Int32 Protocol,UInt32 PortCOM, CallbackRcvData Callback)
    {
        int result = 0;
        result = OpenConnection(TargetName, ref this.ConnectionId, Login, Password, 0, Protocol, 0, 0, Callback,0);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Parameter cannot be null", "original");
        }
    }
}


public class callingClass
{
    ...in some Method   
    ptrFct = new myClass.CallbackRcvData(this.RcvData);

    public int RcvData(UInt32 ConnectionId,IntPtr Data, Int32 size, Int32 Status)
    {
        if ((size > 0) && (Status == 0) && (Data != null))
        {
            this.Displaytext(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(Data));
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public void ThreadProc()
    {
        try
        {
            //open putty session , portCOM not used in this example not serial link
            Session.Create(Settings.DeviceAdd, Settings.Login, Settings.Password, Settings.protocol, 0, ptrFct);                
            this.Connection_End(1);
        }
        catch
        {
            this.Connection_End(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the bad code formatting. I just find it very difficult to use the format options here.

Answer (score 0):

> the function in the code just states the delegate as a parameter, but that parameter/delegate does not have the required parameters from his own definition

When you try to pass a class as a parameter to a method, do you need to include all of the methods in that class in the parameter list?  Do you need to provide all of the properties of the class, etc?

The whole *point* of defining the delegate is to be the place where you define what the signature of the method is so that elsewhere you can just use the delegate identifier to refer to a method matching that signature.

Comment: I think I get it. The delegate *Callback*, which can be understood as a pointer to a function, is referenced to the *OpenConnection* Function, which in turn calls the referenced Function with parameters.